# T420 RAM Upgrade to 2*8

Tags: memory, lenovo-laptop

I have lenovo T420:

Intel® Core™ i5-2410M 2.3 GHz processor with dual-core
DDR3 memory controller (up to 1333MHz), 3MB cache,

OS is 64-bit,

My laptop has 2*4G RAM and I like to upgrade it to 2*8G DDR3 RAM, is the mainboard compatible and everything will work if I do so?

Answer (score 0):

According to the German [thinkwiki](https://thinkwiki.de/T420#Technische_Daten) ([google translated](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=de&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fthinkwiki.de%2FT420%23Technische_Daten)), 2x8GB were successfully tested with the following modules:

- 2x8GB DDR3 (1333MHz), Kingston KTL-TP3B/8G CL9
- 2x8GB Crucial Ballistix Sport SO-DIMM Kit 16GB DDR3L-1866
- 2x8GB HyperX Impact black DDR3-1866 SO-DIMM CL11

Answer (score 0):

I've upgraded dozens of these at the office to 4+8 and 8+8 (which is the maximum) combinations.
It will work, but make sure that you use RAM of at least 1333 MHz and that both strips us exactly the same timing. (E.g. Combining CL7 and CL9 may not be stable.)

We had problems with 1066 MHz modules even though those in theory should have worked. 
Faster modules (1666, never tried 1866) worked fine.
The T420 isn't too picky about the RAM. We used Crucial, Geil, Kingston and Hynix modules and they all worked.